# Deleting single image in array of multiple images active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

On my edit page, I have displayed all images of the product uploaded to the active storage database and below it a dedicated delete button for that single image. The code deletes the image if I manually insert the id, but the id sent by my code gives the location of the image in the array. How do I find the actual id linked to the image from the array location number?

If there is an easier method to do this that would also be appreciated.

views/admin/products/_formedit.html.erb

```
<% (0...@admin_product.images.count).each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag(@admin_product.images[image]) %>
  <%= link_to 'Remove', delete_image_attachment_admin_product_url(image), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

controllers/admin/products_controller.rb

```
def delete_image_attachment
  @image = ActiveStorage::Attachment.find(params[:id])
  @image.purge
  redirect_to contact_url
end
```

routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :products do
    member do
      delete :delete_image_attachment
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: is this the image object? @admin_product.images[image]

Answer (score 2):

Lets start by making the routes less wonky.

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :products do
    resources :images, only: :destroy
  end
end
```

This creates a  RESTful nested route `DELETE /admin/products/:product_id/images/:id` instead of a strange RPC style `delete_image_attachment` route. You can also use the [`shallow: true`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting) option to de-nest the route if the image id is unique. The problem with your route is that it includes an ID but its in the wrong place. When you look at:

```
products/1/delete_image_attachment
```

It would imply that it deletes the attachment for `products/1`. And not the image with id 1 with is what is actually happening.

When your iterating just iterate through the collection and not its indices:

```
<% @admin_product.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag(image) %>
  <%= link_to 'Remove', 
              admin_product_image_path(@admin_product, image), 
              method: :delete, 
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } 
  %>
<% end %>
```

Don't do `each |index|` and then get the item with `things[index]` in Ruby. Its an anti-pattern and `@admin_product.images.count` creates a completely avoidable database query. If you need both the item and its position use `each_with_index`.

Comment: This.  GJ max, beat me to it! The key difference max is iterating through the image objects and not a number range as in OPs question.

Comment: Thanks for your post, much appreciated. I am now getting an error "uninitialized constant Admin::ImagesController", do I need an image controller?

Comment: Yes. Don't do this in your ProductsController.